# Rails: Render JSON with associated models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I apologize if this is a dumb question, but I'm having trouble rendering JSON in a reasonable time. I feel like I'm overlooking something simple. This is an API endpoint for an Angular 2 SPA.

I have a **Bookmark** model, which *has_many* **Tags**.

```
class Bookmark < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :taggings
  has_many :tags, through: :taggings
end
```

The *idea* is that a user logs in, and is shown their bookmarks - paginated - and each bookmark displays their associated *Tags*.

The *problem* is that I ran into the n+1 query issue. With thousands of objects, it was taking rails upwards of 2 minutes to render the JSON. This led me to installing the *bullet gem* and using eager loading.

```
# bookmarks_controller.rb
def index
  @bookmarks = Bookmark.includes(:taggings, :tags).where(user_id: @current_user.id).order('created_at DESC')

  render json: @bookmarks, :include => :tags
end
```

So this sped up the *query* time, but the actual rendering process is still taking forever.

At this point, I tried to use the *Oj gem* to optimize the JSON. This increased the render speed greatly!

```
def index
  @bookmarks = Bookmark.where(user_id: @current_user.id).order('created_at DESC')

  render json: Oj.dump(@bookmarks, mode: :compat)
end
```

The problem here is that the bullet gem advises to remove the eager loading, and *Oj isn't rendering the associated Tags*. If I include the eager loading, it still takes about 2 minutes to load which is ridiculous. I can't seem to find any documentation about including associations.

What can I do to make this faster *and* include the associated Tags? Is this idea even feasible or should I change directions?

Any help will be greatly appreciated! I've been banging my head on my desk for several days now. If you need more info just let me know and I'll be happy to provide it.

*EDIT* Here are the requested tables:

```
create_table "bookmarks", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "name"
  t.string "url"
  t.boolean "reading_list"
  t.bigint "user_id"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  t.integer "view_count", default: 0
  t.integer "folder_id"
  t.boolean "is_favorite", default: false
  t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_bookmarks_on_user_id"
end

create_table "tags", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "name"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end

create_table "taggings", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.bigint "tag_id"
  t.bigint "bookmark_id"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  t.bigint "folder_id"
  t.index ["bookmark_id"], name: "index_taggings_on_bookmark_id"
  t.index ["folder_id"], name: "index_taggings_on_folder_id"
  t.index ["tag_id"], name: "index_taggings_on_tag_id"
end

add_foreign_key "taggings", "bookmarks"
add_foreign_key "taggings", "folders"
add_foreign_key "taggings", "tags"
```

Comment: Try https://github.com/rails/jbuilder with paginate

Comment: You're probably missing an index somewhere... can you paste the Bookmarks, taggings, and tags tables from `schema.rb`?

Comment: Thanks @SujanAdiga, I'll check that out.

Comment: Thanks @patkoperwas, you may be onto something but I'm not sure what I'm missing... think I've been staring for too long! I uploaded the OP with the tables you asked for. Thanks for your time

Comment: You could profile it to see where it's using the cpu...

Comment: How many records do you have in your `taggings` and `tags` tables?

Comment: @jeffdill2 not very many, less than 75 at the moment.

Comment: @rogerdpack Thanks for the suggestion, but I'm not sure how to do that...

Comment: @tdog 75 records is beyond insignificant. You should be seeing query speeds in the single digits of milliseconds. Is this running on your local machine or in some production environment? If it's your local machine, what hardware are you running it on and is it on a virtual machine?

Comment: @jeffdill2 Yeah I know. There are roughly 6k Bookmark objects, but the tags/taggings are much smaller. I'm running it locally, not the fastest machine ever (macbook pro, 2.66ghz i7, 8gb ram) but never anywhere close to this slow. I'd honestly like for that to be my problem here! :P

Comment: @tdog very odd, those are some decently beefy specs. What database are you running? Also, I'm assuming the app is running directly on your machine, not like on a Docker instance or something like that?

Comment: @jeffdill2 I'm using postgresql and directly on my machine. Thanks a bunch for your help so far

Comment: What result do you get from benchmarking your query? – `Benchmark.measure { Bookmark.includes(:taggings, :tags).where(user_id: @current_user.id).order('created_at DESC') }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160646/discussion-between-tdog-and-jeffdill2).